# How do I make a method that prints according to the different classes I have?

Tags: java

```
public class TestDoctor{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Doctor doc = new Doctor();
        Doctor surg = new Surgeon();
        Doctor ped = new Pediatrician();
    }
}
```

I have 3 other classes. Doctor is the superclass. And Surgeon and Pediatrician are the Subclasses. Each of those classes have a method called treatPatient that prints a statement. I "overrided" the toString method for each of them to print the class name and I overrided the println statement for the subclasses as well. The Surgeon class has one more println statement. I need to make a method after the main method that I wrote above. This has to do with polymorphism so I'm confused. The method I want to write here is going to take in a parameter of the superclass (Doctor) TYPE. And so it should print the stuff for the doctor class. Then it should print out the stuff for the Surgeon class. And then it should print out the stuff for the pediatrician class. So how do I write that method.  Like this?:

```
public void docMethod(Doctor x){
   x.toString();
   x.treatPatient();
}
```

And also how would I cast another method from the surgeon class as well into this docMethod. I was told it's if/then using instanceof and then calling that method. Please help. I've tried really hard sitting here for hours :(

Comment: Your attached method "docMethod" does exactly why you want to do I suppose. You just have to call that method with doc, then surg and ped.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking. But there are some things you might want to know: When dealing with polymorphism you don't need to worry about which method is called. See the following example:

```
public void docMethod(Doctor x){
   x.toString();
   x.treatPatient();
}

public void doSomething() {
    docMethod(new Doctor()); //calls toString() and treatPatient() for the doctor
    docMethod(new Surgeon()); //calls those methods that are overwritten in surgeon
    //and so on
}
```

So if you have overwritten those methods, the polymorphism does what you expect (as far as I understand your question correct).

Anyway, if you have a method within e.g. the Surgeon that doesn't exist in the Doctor class, but you still want to use the method you posted, you can use `instanceof` to call that method on a Doctor object:

```
public void docMethod(Doctor x){
   x.toString();
   x.treatPatient();
   if (x instanceof Surgeon) {
      //Do something only surgeons can do
   }
}
```

But remember, using instanceof can be quite confusing in your context.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still having trouble as to why it didn't work. And casting after the instanceof is a problem for me.